# Multiple models in same view in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using asp.net mvc 4 & Entity Framework 6 to make a website where after user login, the table records will show & the ID of the user will show as `Session`. But when I run, after login, I get this error, `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` I've made a custom model where two DbSet from seperate EF6 models are attached. My code is below,

**Custom Model**

```
public class MkistatVsUserLogin
{
    public sample_1 sample_1 { get; set; }  //Login Model
    public IEnumerable<mkistat> mkistats { get; set; }  //Table Model
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(sample_1 id)
{            
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var uservar = db.sample_1.Where(a => a.boid.Equals(id.boid)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (uservar != null)
        {
            Session["UserBOID"] = uservar.boid.ToString();
            return RedirectToAction("UserLogin");
        }
    }
    var mkimodel = new MkistatVsUserLogin { mkistats = dsedb.mkistats.ToList() };
    return View(id);
    return View(mkimodel);
}
```

**View**

```
@model ABCoLtd.Models.MkistatVsUserLogin
@if (Session["UserBOID"] != null)
{
    <li>Welcome, <b>@Session["UserBOID"].ToString()</b></li>
}
<a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action("UserLogout", "Home")">Log Out</a>
@foreach (var item in Model.mkistats)
{    
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MKISTAT_ID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MKISTAT_PHONE_NO)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code? If it is then please give me a solution. All I want is to use both models at the same view where user login model will be used in `Session` & table model to list all the records.

Comment: Your post method has `return View(id);` (the following line where you return `mkimodel` is ignored). In any case it looks like you should be redirecting, not return the view

Comment: How can I redirect with passing the session value & the table value?

Comment: Pass table as model in parameter, and use ViewBag to pass ID

Comment: Can you give me an example with code?

Comment: Why not create view model combining both id and other type and pass it as along with view. Why r u returning view twice?

Comment: @qamar, Error statement.

Comment: remove return view(id). You main model never gets passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I just made another method in controller for viewing table with user session.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(sample_1 id)
    {            
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var uservar = db.sample_1.Where(a => a.boid.Equals(id.boid)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (uservar != null)
            {
                Session["UserBOID"] = uservar.boid.ToString();
                return RedirectToAction("UserLogin");
            }
        }
        return View(id);            
    }

    public ActionResult UserLogin()
    {
        if(Session["UserBOID"] != null)
        {
            var mkimodel = new MkistatVsUserLogin { mkistats = dsedb.mkistats.ToList() };
            return View(mkimodel);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks good, that's what I said in my answer, `and in your return View line also mention View or ActionMethod name`, anyways that's good you got it.

Comment: Tnx for the help, but who the hell 'minus vote' my post? That's rude.

Answer (score 1):

Remove bellow line

```
return View(id);
```

and in your return View line also mention View or ActionMethod name

```
return View("ViewName",mkimodel)
```

In your action method, Use Session to pass ID

```
Session["UserID"] = id;
```

You can use the same in your View as :

```
<html>
-----Your CODE
<body>
------Your CODE
    @Session["UserID"]
------Your CODE
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does ViewBag works like `Session`? Sorry for asking, I'm new to Asp.net.

Comment: ViewBag will be for one request only, from your controller to view only, if you want to use it in all your pages then go for `Session[UserId]`

Comment: Thats the problem, I've many other pages. So I must use `Session[UserId]`, how can I pass that without `return View(id)`?

Comment: Simply set it in session, let me update the code for you

Comment: Still showing the same error. Its pointing out that the line `@foreach (var item in Model.mkistats)` has error. Any thought?

Comment: I got it. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can create a ViewModel to handle :</strike>

```
namespace ABCoLtd.ViewModels
{
  public class LoginVM
  {

     public MkistatVsUserLogin MkistatVsUserLogin {get;set;}
     public int Id {get;set;}
  }
}
```

and in action pass this way:

```
var mkimodel = new MkistatVsUserLogin { mkistats = dsedb.mkistats.ToList() };
LoginVM vm = new LoginVM();
vm.MkistatVsUserLogin  = mkimodel ;
vm.Id = id;
return View(vm );
```

and in View set model to LoginVM:

```
@model ABCoLtd.ViewModels.LoginVM
```

### UPDATE:

you already have a viewmodel didnt noticed that, you just need to do this:

```
var mkimodel = new MkistatVsUserLogin 
                  { 
                    mkistats = dsedb.mkistats.ToList(),
                    sample_1 = id
                     };
return View(nkimodel);
```

Comment: In this line, `vm.Id = id;` id cannot be converted into int.

Answer (score 0):

After login you are directly redirecting your user to an action and that action you have not mentioned here.And that action whose view you have shown is an strongly typed view which expects a list of `MkistatVsUserLogin`. But, I think you are not passing that list, so `Model` property of view will remain null and that will be causing an error of object reference. Please check this issue.